# change image on hover moves images

Tags: css, image, hover

I'm having a bit of problem here.

I'm trying to display an image in a circle div (using bootstrap), that when hover, the picture becomes a gif, but if you take your mouse from over the picture, it is only a static image.

It works, almost, as it moves the picture and the frame around, and I can not find why.

Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/eve_mf/zmp7tnho/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="titleColumns col-md-24">
<h1>Meet Some Of <strong>Our Denison Experts</strong></h1>
<h2>We can have a line about the team</h2>
<div class="personPic col-md-6">
<div class="circleFrame"><img class="static img-circle alignleft wp-image-1008 size-full" src="http://motors06.denison-automotive.co.uk/denison/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/jules_sil5.png" alt="" width="120" height="120" />
<img class="animated img-circle alignleft wp-image-1008 size-full" src="http://motors06.denison-automotive.co.uk/denison/wp-content/themes/denison-automotive/images/jules_sil_gif.gif" alt="" width="120" height="120" /></div>
<span class="peopleName">Jules Perry</span>
<span class="peoplePos">The Thinker</span>

</div>
<div class="personPic col-md-6">
<div class="circleFrame"><img class="static img-circle alignleft wp-image-1012 size-full" src="http://motors06.denison-automotive.co.uk/denison/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/tessa_sil2.png" alt="" width="120" height="120" />
<img class="animated img-circle alignleft wp-image-1012 size-full" src="http://motors06.denison-automotive.co.uk/denison/wp-content/themes/denison-automotive/images/tessa_sil_gif.gif" alt="" width="120" height="120" /></div>
<span class="peopleName">Tessa Denison</span>
<span class="peoplePos">The Creative</span>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

I'm just working with html and css

Any suggestions? I've tried to remove all the styles but even then, there is a movement between the pictures and are the same size..

Thank youuuu

Comment: Absolutely positioned elements are removed from the document flow so your page is actually changing layout. I think you may need to brush up on the way positioning works. I'm not sure the way you're going about it is optimal.

Comment: Images are not avaliable without auth in your fiddle. Please use public urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you don't need to set a position at all.

```
.circleFrame:hover .animated {
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zmp7tnho/4/

Comment: thanks!!

Actually it works here in the jsfiddle but in my template is still moving, it is a smaller movement though, I will keep trying.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to set border styles to `circleFrame` too - http://jsfiddle.net/d3z849y7/

It helps you with freezing borders.

Comment: done it, and not change get :/ it's super odd because I've opened a new html and I've just put this code and these styles and it is still doing the same.

Is it possible because the images are not the same format? it sounds idiot... isn't it? ogggg I'm fustrated!